# window.onload doesn't run the whole function (javascript)

Tags: javascript, window, onload

I tried to make this function getWeekly() run by default when the site first loads but it only runs this part of the code:

```
dailyBtn.classList.add("active");
weeklyBtn.classList.remove("active");
monthlyBtn.classList.remove("active");
```

but not the loop under. But it'll show data when I click on the tags. Any ideas? Thanks.

Git link: https://github.com/thusmiley/time-tracking-dashboard.git
Live site link: https://thusmiley.github.io/time-tracking-dashboard

index.html

```
<div class="report-bottom">
          <a href="#" id="daily" onclick="getDaily()">Daily</a>
          <a href="#" id="weekly" onclick="getWeekly()">Weekly</a>
          <a href="#" id="monthly" onclick="getMonthly()">Monthly</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="stat-wrapper">
        <div class="work-bg bg"></div>
        <div class="stat" id="work">
          <div class="category">
            <h2>Work</h2>
            <img src="./images/icon-ellipsis.svg" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <h3 class="work-current"></h3>
            <p class="work-previous"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

script.js

```
let Data = [];

fetch("./data.json")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => Data.push(...data));

  let card = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
  let dailyBtn = document.getElementById("daily");
  let weeklyBtn = document.getElementById("weekly");
  let monthlyBtn = document.getElementById("monthly");
  
  
  function getDaily() {...    }
    
    function getWeekly() {
      dailyBtn.classList.remove("active");
      weeklyBtn.classList.add("active");
      monthlyBtn.classList.remove("active");
      
      for (let i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) {
        let splitTitle = Data[i].title.split("");
        splitTitle = splitTitle.filter((e) => String(e).trim());
        let joinTitle = splitTitle.join("");
        
        let current = document.querySelector(`.${joinTitle.toLowerCase()}-current`);
        let previous = document.querySelector(
          `.${joinTitle.toLowerCase()}-previous`
          );
          current.innerHTML = `${Data[i].timeframes.weekly.current + "hrs"}`;
          previous.innerHTML = `${
            "Last Week - " + Data[i].timeframes.weekly.previous + "hrs"
          }`;
        }
      }
      
      function getMonthly() {...        }
        
        window.onload = getWeekly();
```

Comment: When you assign to `window.onload` you should assign the function name, not a call to the function. `window.onload = getWeekly` without the `()`.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys, appreciate it. I tried all that too and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first time that you load the page `Data.length` is equal to 0, and that's why the loop doesn't iterate. You are using an asynchronous call to load `Data`, and when `getWeekly()` is called for the first time, `Data` is not ready with the info yet (and it only works after when its ready).

You should wait until `Data` is completely load first, you can try a callback function or even try `$.when()` using [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/).

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thank you. 

I tried to add this to the script:
window.onload = function () {
  $.when(Data.length > 0).then(getWeekly());
};

But it's still not working for me :(. Any thoughts? Sorry, I'm new to js.

Comment: Don't worry. The general idea is use `$.when()` for a Promise, so you won't be able to 'wait' for `Data.length > 0`.  Here you have a simple pastebin with the idea you should use: https://pastebin.com/22wfvM0K

Comment: So basically,  you let the promise inside `$when()`  and wait until it resolves. Once is done, you can work with the response and fill Data with the info, and then call your function with Data ready. Btw, the `$(document).ready` works when the document is 'ready', similar to window.onload but for Jquery.

Comment: Thanks @matias. I don't know much enough about jquery to make it work so I asked around and found this, it fixed the problem:

async function loadDefault() {
  const response = await fetch("./data.json");
  const parsedResponse = await response.json()
  let updateData = (data) => Data.push(...data)
  updateData(parsedResponse)
  getWeekly()
}

loadDefault()